# How to produce output using show function

Tags: c++

I am trying to use sho to show the output of another function.The first function was used to do sorting, and returned a List.

now I want to make a function that uses show() to display the output.This is how I had tried it only to get an error.

Its to diplay the results of two the two sorted lists which used this function.

```
    //Function that does the compare!

    map<int, Bid*> Auctioneer::compareBidList(map<int, Bid*>& one, map<int, Bid*>& 
                   two) // pass references &
     {
  map<int, Bid*> Sorted;
       map<int, Bid*>::iterator iterOne;
  for(iterOne = one.begin(); iterOne != one.end(); ++iterOne)
 {
    if(iterOne->second->bidType == 'A') // select all type A from one
    {
        map<int, Bid*>::iterator iterTwo;
        for(iterTwo = two.begin(); iterTwo != two.end(); ++iterTwo)
        {
            if(iterTwo->second->bidType == 'B') // select all
         type B from two
            {
                if(iterOne->second->price < iterTwo->second-
                          >price) // select on price between type A and type B
                {
                    Sorted.insert(*iterOne);
                    Sorted.insert(*iterTwo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }                
   return Sorted;
   }

 void show(map<int, Bid*>& one, map<int, Bid*>& two) { 
    map<int, Bid*>::iterator iterOne;
    map<int, Bid*>::iterator iterTwo;
   cout << "-----------------The sorted List-------------------------";     
   for(iterOne=Sorted.begin(); iterOne!= Sorted.end(); iterOne++){
   cout << iterOne->second->toString() << endl<<"\n";}
   for(iterTwo=Sorted.begin(); iterTwo!= Sorted.end(); iterTwo){
   cout << iterTwo->second->toString() << endl<<"\n";}  
   }  

 void show(const char *msg, map<int, Bid*>& Sorted) {  
       cout << msg << endl; 
       show(Sorted);
        }  
void compare(map<int, Bid*>& sellers, map<int, Bid*>& buyers) { 
    compare(sellers.begin(), sellers.end(),
    buyers.begin(),buyers.end(),compareBidList); } 

//my call in the main after declaration was as follows
   map<int, Bid*> buyers, sellers;
   auctioneer.compare(sellers,buyers);
   show("Bids after sorting:", sellers); 
   show(buyers);
```

Comment: We're gonna need a bit more than that. What should `show` do? Print to a console, display a window, write to a browser, launch a skywriting airplane?

Comment: When you get an error, you have to tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra parenthesis, and call show twice (your declaration only takes one map object):

```
show("Bids after sorting:", sellers);
show(buyers);
```

Comment: There's also no function defined (that I can see) that takes two `map` s, and there's no function defined that takes a `map` and nothing else... those two functions will need to be defined for anything to actually work...

Comment: @codeka: The show function taking two arguments prints a message and delegates to a single argument show function, which I assumed was defined elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it's the "defined elsewhere" that I was worried about. It seems to be important (too important to just leave it out?)... I guess when we see the actual errors we'll know for sure :)